# Unintended Redirects with UrlFetchApp

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I try to make a web viewer using the `UrlFetchApp` Google Apps Script API. For most websites it gets the html correctly, then displays it on the page, but for some websites, such as Reddit or Wattpad, it displays it for a split second then redirects to this link:

> https://n-uwt7obrrett4kk3vudl45czwy7kyfbpw7bcneuq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel.

To give the URL of the website to display, you attach a query to the web app URL like `?url=https://example.com`.

Are the unintended redirections something in my code, or are the websites themselves trying to redirecting it?

Here's my code:

```
function doGet(e) {
 var param = e["parameter"]["url"];
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(param);
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response);
}
```

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I could confirm your situation. I'm sorry.

Comment: Maybe they don't like getting scraped by Google Users.

Comment: I agree with @Cooper 's comment. In this case, I think that if you don't want to do the redirect, each page is required to be analyzed and remove the issue.

Comment: @Tanaike What do you mean by that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I thought that in order to not make the page redirect, after the HTML was retrieved using `UrlFetchApp`, it is required to analyze and modified the page. But I think that it is difficult to do.

Comment: @Tanaike That's fine! Do you have any suggestions on how to modify the page?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot propose a sample script for resolving your issue for all pages. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi ! In your case what would represent ```e```? I tried to reproduce this in a simple function with no triggers to see what I get but I could not figure out which parameters are you passing. Is it the URL of reddit? Also, what are you intending to do with this, to get the plan HTML of any page? Thanks ! :D

Comment: @MateoRandwolf It's a web-app. `e` will be sent, when a user visits the web app. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: You can use [**UrlFetchApp.fetch** method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) with **followRedirects** advanced parameter to get more information.